# Issue with outputting exe file in IDA Pro 6.8

Tags: assembly, intel, ida

I'm using IDA Pro on my Windows 10 machine. I disassembled a simple exe file into Intel x86 assembly and then changed some instructions. Now I want to output an exe file. I've already tried `pe_write.idc` script to output exe file but it didn't work. What should I do to output exe file?

Answer (score 2):

Disassembling and then reassembling code in this way is very error prone.  There is no guarantee that what is disassembled can actually be successfully reassembled into working code.  I don't have a reference really handy for that, but I know there is one.

If you need to make modifications, the better way to do it, in my experience, is to identify what you need to modify, figure out identifying byte patterns surrounding it and then modify the binary directly.